# Array Append Multiple Array Items - Swift

Tags: swift

I want to combine arrays, but the join I want is as follows:
I want the items of the Arrays that I want to combine. For example, I want to create a new array by combining the first item of ImageBannerLogo with the first item of ImageBannerLogo1 and the first item of ImageBannerLogo2.

```
    var ımageBannerLogo = [String]()
    var ımageBannerLogo1 = [String]()
    var ımageBannerLogo2 = [String]()
    var ımageBannerLogoAll = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
ımageBannerLogo.append("one", "two", "three")
ımageBannerLogo1.append("1", "2", "3")
ımageBannerLogo2.append("4", "5", "6")

ımageBannerLogoAll.append(ımageBannerLogo+ ımageBannerLogo1+ ımageBannerLogo2)
}
```

I want its output to be as follows: ımageBannerLogoAll = "one14","two25","three36"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ımageBannerLogo = ["one", "two", "three"]
var ımageBannerLogo1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
var ımageBannerLogo2 = ["4", "5", "6"]
var ımageBannerLogoAll = [String]()
```

Just iterate and format the string

```
    func loopIT() {
       //Include this check to avoid crash - array index out if range 
       guard ımageBannerLogo.count == ımageBannerLogo1.count && ımageBannerLogo.count == ımageBannerLogo2.count else { return }

       for i in 0..<ımageBannerLogo.count {
            ımageBannerLogoAll.append(String(format: "%@%@%@", ımageBannerLogo[i], ımageBannerLogo1[i], ımageBannerLogo2[i]))
       }

       print(ımageBannerLogoAll)
       //["one14", "two25", "three36"]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append a sequence to an array this way.
(See [append(contentsOf:) doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126939-append))

```swift
ımageBannerLogo.append(contentsOf: ["one", "two", "three"])
ımageBannerLogo1.append(contentsOf: ["1", "2", "3"])
ımageBannerLogo2.append(contentsOf: ["4", "5", "6"])
```

You can then put them together with for loop like this.

```swift
for i in 0..<ımageBannerLogo.count {
    ımageBannerLogoAll.append(ımageBannerLogo[i] + ımageBannerLogo1[i] + ımageBannerLogo2[i])
}
```

Or, use `zip` and `map` like this.

```swift
ımageBannerLogoAll += zip(zip(ımageBannerLogo, ımageBannerLogo1), ımageBannerLogo2).map { $0.0 + $0.1 + $1 }
```

Comment: [+=](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var ımageBannerLogo:[String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
    var ımageBannerLogo1:[String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    var ımageBannerLogo2 :[String] = ["4", "5", "6"]
    var ımageBannerLogoAll:[String] = []


for i in 0..<ımageBannerLogo.count{
    ımageBannerLogoAll.append("\(ımageBannerLogo[i])\(ımageBannerLogo1[i])\(ımageBannerLogo2[i])")
}


print(ımageBannerLogoAll)
//Result : ["one14", "two25", "three36"]
```